# RecyclerView onBindViewHolder click listener changes contents of wrong cell

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a recyclerview from a list of Food Items. When you click on the item, I want the item to be greyed out. Now this does work, and the first item I press, does indeed turn grey. However when I press it again, some other cells turn grey. Then it turns into a big mess, with random ones greyed out?

I have set it up that when you click the item, the FoodItem instance has a boolean set. Then I refresh the data of the recyclerview, so that items with the boolean set, have a grey overlay.

Here is my adapter:

[

```
public class FoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    ClickListener clickListener;

    private List<FoodItem> foodList;

    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void ItemClicked(View v, int position);
    }



    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView quantity;
        public RelativeLayout background;
        public LinearLayout eatenOverlay;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_item_name);
            quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_item_quantity);
            background = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.food_item_background_relative_layout);
            eatenOverlay = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.eaten_overlay);
        }
    }

    public FoodAdapter(List<FoodItem> foodList) {
        this.foodList = foodList;
    }


    @Override
    public FoodAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.food_item_list, parent, false);



        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FoodAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        FoodItem currentFoodItem = foodList.get(position);

        if(currentFoodItem.isHasBeenEaten()){
            holder.eatenOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        Resources res = holder.itemView.getContext().getResources();

        holder.name.setText(currentFoodItem.getName());
        holder.quantity.setText(currentFoodItem.getQuantity());

        holder.background.setBackgroundResource(currentFoodItem.getImage());

        holder.background.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.ItemClicked(v, position);
                }
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foodList.size();
    }
}
```

And the main activity implements the interface, so when the item is clicked, in the main acitivty I have this code;

```
 @Override
    public void ItemClicked(View v, int position) {

        foodList.get(position).setHasBeenEaten(true);
        Log.d(TAG,foodList.get(position).getName() + " clicked");
        Log.d(TAG,"position: " + position);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Why is this happening? Thanks

Comment: you should implement onclick listener in ViewHolder class and get position from getAdapterPosiotion(); https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing the other option.

```
 if(currentFoodItem.isHasBeenEaten()){
      holder.eatenOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 } else {
      holder.eatenOverlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 }
```

needed an else branch, otherwise because of the recycling you may reuse the previous view, with the previous "configuration".

Comment: Thanks, That was it!

Comment: was about to comment the same, that's quite a quick response :P